# Using multiple patterns to validate html5 input

Tags: regex, html

I am asking user to enter a valid folder name in form input.

Requirements:

1. Minimum 3 characters.

   pattern=".{3,}"
2. A valid folder name.

   pattern="^[\w.-]+$"

How can I validate input against both the patterns?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
pattern="[\w.-]{3,}"
```

You need no anchors in [HTML5 pattern attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) as they are implied by default.

> The regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).

The `[\w.-]{3,}` pattern matches 3 or more (`{3,}`) characters that are either ASCII letters/digits/underscores, a dot or a hyphen.